# How to disable redux devtool to hide state in browser after production?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, google-chrome-devtools

I built and deployed a MERN web app.

How can I disable redux devtools to stop showing state to users? otherwise anyone with devtools chrome extension can view all the data in state. I do not want to remove it from dev mode, is there any way to hide all state just for production?

Source code: https://github.com/deepak-punia/complaint-management-software
Deployed app: https://complaint-management-software.herokuapp.com/
[image: redux state]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can you use a boolean value in `createStore` and use `process.env.NODE_ENV` to get the current environment to toggle it conditionally.

Something like this

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReduce,
    users: usersReduce,
  },
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});

export default store;
```